# Sublattice of the weight lattice

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

Recently, I am studying Lie algebra and have some question for the root system.

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a simple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak h$ a cartan subalgebra and $\Delta$ the root system of $\mathfrak g$

Let $O_{\mathfrak g}$ be the sublattice of the weight lattice spanned by long roots and $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l\}$ a set of simple roots.

Weight lattice $\Lambda_w$ is the set $\{\lambda \in \mathfrak h^*|\langle\lambda, \alpha^\vee\rangle\in \mathbb Z \text{ for all } \alpha\in R\}$

($\alpha^{\vee}=\frac{2}{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle}\alpha$, and $\langle\text{ },\text{ }\rangle$ is an invariant bilinear form on $\mathfrak g$ normalized by $\langle \theta,\theta\rangle=2$, where $\theta$ is the highest root.)

In the irreducible root system, there are two lengths on roots. Since root system of a simple lie algebra is irreducible, we can think long roots and short roots.(In the semisimple case, we cannot say long and short root?)

Author says that

Lemma: The sublattice $O_\mathfrak g\subset\mathfrak h$ is generated by $\{\frac{2}{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle}\alpha|\alpha\in\Delta\}$. If $\mathfrak g$ is $A_n,D_n,E_n(resp. B_n,C_n,F_4,G_2)$, then $O_\mathfrak g$ is isomorphic to the root lattice(resp. $D_n, A_1^n,D_4,A_2).$

I understand the lemma as follows(Actually I don't know how to prove the lemma).

$O_\mathfrak g$ is a coroot lattice and in case of $\mathfrak g \text{ is }A_n,D_n,E_n$, this coroot lattice is isomorphic the the root lattice(Is it right?)

However $O_\mathfrak g$ is spanned by long roots and simple roots which are all element in $\Delta$ and this gives me confusion.

Since $O_\mathfrak g$ already contains all simple roots and all roots are $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of simple roots,

I think that $O_\mathfrak g$ is just a root lattice.

Does I misunderstand some basic concept?

Comment: At first you seem to define $O_\mathfrak{g}$ as the root lattice but then your Lemma defines it as the coroot lattice which definitely does not contain the roots in general as it is spanned by the coroots of the simple roots, not the simple roots themselves.

Comment: As to your parenthetical question about the semisimple case. No we can't talk about only two root lengths in that case. We can talk about the roots which are long/short in each simple ideal but between the simple ideals these lengths will differ.

Comment: Just saying that in the case of one root length (i.e. ADE), all roots are "long" roots, while in the other cases BCFG, that list describes the sub-root system made up of the long roots (the long roots in $B_n$ form a root system of type $D_n$, etc.).

Comment: @Callum Thank you!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Oh I misunderstood what author said. Thank you!